# Principle of mathematical Induction

Tags: logic

Proving some statement by using the principle of mathematical induction is an example of inductive reasoning. But as we know conclusion by using inductive reasoning is just a conjecture. But in the case of mathematical induction the result is true.

So can we say that the principle of mathematical induction is an example of inductive reasoning which gives us only true results always?

Answer (score 3):

The principle of mathematical induction allows us to make a *deduction* based on an inductive property. It is the formalisation of inductive reasoning into mathematics, yes, but it is still an example of a deductive reasoning:

> **If** $0\in A$ and $n\in A\to n+1\in A$, **then** for all $n\in\Bbb N$, $n\in A$.

It is taken either as an axiom, in some contexts (e.g. Peano axioms for the natural numbers), or we can prove it from other axioms (e.g. Zermelo–Fraenkel set theory). It can also be generalised to other contexts, like transfinite induction or well-founded induction.

Answer (score 2):

Mathematical *induction* (perhaps a misnomer) is *not* an example so-called inductive reasoning. It is actually a form of *deductive* reasoning.

> Deductive reasoning, also deductive logic, is the process of reasoning
> from one or more statements (premises [or axioms or theorems]) to reach a logically certain
> conclusion. [Deductive reasoning - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deductive_reasoning)

The Principle of [Mathematical Induction](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/InductionAxiom.html) is actually an axiom (or theorem in some systems). Every proof by induction is implicitly an application of this axiom/theorem.

Answer (score 1):

In mathematics Principle of mathematical Induction can be considered as "axiom" or theorem depending in which theory you look at it. Info can be found on [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_induction#Formalization), but as I prefer books as source, then Nicolas Bourbaki - Theory of sets - page 168. imho is good place to look at.

Suppose
$$R(0) \text{ and } (\forall n)((n\text{ is integer and }R(n))\Rightarrow R(n+1))$$
is theorem in some theory. Then
$$(\forall n)((n\text{ is integer})\Rightarrow R(n))$$
is also theorem in same theory.

Comment: Bourbaki's set theory book is a terrible source for almost anything, with the exception (perhaps) of how to botch a set theory exposition and make generations of mathematician feel that set theory is an unnecessary formalism that nobody should care for.

Comment: @Asaf Karagila. I am aware with this view and wait similar reaction. While my post does not suggest to start study set theory with this book, but use it as source to OP answer, then I have my strict objections against misleading the audience not familiar with the subject. The "Description of Formal Mathematics" brought in Bourbaki's set theory is best place to understand what mathematics is. Not counting one-sided declarative statements as argumentation, I am kindly ready for a constructive discussion. If you agree we can use some chat for it.